# Tracking in video: Offset an entire track?

Tags: video, tracking

I'm tracking a clear object in my video for stabilization that is moving in the direction I want it to, however I want the actual video to not stabilize on this location, but rather at a point that is underneath this object at all times. I know I can offset individual track points, but is it possible to offset the entire track once it is finished?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you are asking. In the compositor you can add a translate node after the stabilize 2D node:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/8qmme.png if what you want to do is offset the placement of the stabilized video

Comment: If @cegaton didn't already answer your question (in that case you should use the answer function here and quickly explain the steps you took to solve your problem) could you then provide some example images of what you try to achieve?